# Tizen notification, bring app to foreground

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, samsung-gear, samsung-gear-s2

I have created a web app for the Gear S that communicates with a server and I would like to create a notification when the server sends certain data back. I have found the Notification API but I can not use this because it gives errors. I have the same problem that someone posted earlier (https://developer.tizen.org/ko/forums/general-support/notifications-on-gear-s-gear-only-mode?langswitch=en). 
So what I would like is when I receive a message from the server, the Gear S vibrates and brings my app to the foreground. Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: Your error was "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor...", are you sure that your function returs something?
Please check this link https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/notification.html

Comment: Please check my answer from below link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37198258/tizen-app-vibration-background/37215278#37215278](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37198258/tizen-app-vibration-background/37215278#37215278)